# Image/File upload path after making app in Java from Eclipse

Tags: java

I am making a Java-SQL database storing app on Eclipse and MySQL. In this app, I have to upload image to the file directory. Currently while making this app, I am using an image upload path and storing all the uploaded images there. But when I'm finished with the app, and if I'm to work it on someone else's computer the image upload path in the code obviously will not work on that computer. What shall I do to make it work on other computer as well? Should I make a prompt which asks for image upload path every time the app opens and store that, or something else?? please help.

```
private String imageUploadPath = "/home/tsoprano/Documents/eclipse-workspace/enable/src/com/enable/regis/imgupload/";
File file1;

picLabel = new JLabel("  Upload Photo");
    picLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser imageChooser= new JFileChooser();
            if(imageChooser.showOpenDialog(picLabel)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file1 = imageChooser.getSelectedFile();
                ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(imageChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                Image img=icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 150, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                icon= new ImageIcon(img);
                picLabel.setIcon(icon);

            }
        }
    });

//inside the submit button action
    String filePath = imageUploadPath + file1.getName();
            try {
                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file1);
                ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File(filePath));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            rdto.setPicUrl(filePath);
```

Comment: You could make the image upload path a configurable property. Check out how to read a *.properties file: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html . When you want to run the app on another PC, make sure to change the property value before running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest doing this via a config file, because this is not very user-friendly. Instead, get the current directory (i. e. the one that you executed the `java` command) using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. Then create a new folder inside there, and use it as your upload folder. This will make sure you always have a useable path without bothering the user with specifying it.

Comment: can this be used in windows too where eclipse isn't installed? thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Yes it can! It is a standard Java function. But be careful with the paths, as Windiws uses backslashes \ and Linux forward slashes /. You can get the OS you are running with `System.getProperty("os.name")`